# getUserMedia() in JavaScript normalizes across browsers. Illegal Invocation

Tags: javascript, function, getusermedia, invocation

When I try to do the following:

```
var getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
// now I try to invoke it with some parameters:
getUserMedia(...) // not working!
```

It throws an error "Illegal Invocation" in Chrome.

But if I do:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
// now invoke it with the navigator
navigator.getUserMedia(..) // Works
```

I've tried searching a bit, and I read it's a context issue. But I still couldn't understand what's the meaning of that. In the first example, the getUserMedia variable ends up getting a reference to the function which is not undefiend (i.e, in case of chrome, it's webkitGetUserMedia), so why cannot I invoke it using this variable?

<sub>(This is actually a general JavaScript question, not specific to [WebRTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC).)</sub>

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Apparently, it needs the context to be the `navigator` object, for whatever reason. I've noticed the same thing with `console.log` - it needs the `console` context.

When you do `navigator.getUserMedia`, the context is automatically set to `navigator`, as with any other time you invoke a method on an object. If you just do `getUserMedia` though, the context (by default) is global, and so it throws an *Illegal Invocation* error.

If you still want to save it as a variable, you can call it with the correct context at runtime:

```
var getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
// now I try to invoke it with some parameters:  
getUserMedia.call(navigator, ...)
```

You could also use `bind` to save the context with the variable, so that you don't have to call it each time:

```
var getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia).bind(navigator);
// now I try to invoke it with some parameters:  
getUserMedia(...)
```

Comment: Thanks. Are there any performance difference between call(navigator,..) and navigator.getUserMeida ?